# The meaning of もの

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of もの in that sentence
真相を知る**もの**は誰もいません

Dictionary says it can mean 'thing', but also 'really'.

I guess thus it's 'really' but when I automatically translate this sentence, the meaning 'really' never appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

もの has a variety of uses.  While it can mean thing, it can also refer to a person, which is what it's doing in this sentence.

Breaking the sentence down, we have:

> 真相を知る: <*someone*> knows the truth.

> 誰もいません: There is no one.

もの is the glue that ties these two parts together.

First note that, when 真相を知る is placed before もの, it's acting as a relative clause.  So,

> 真相を知るもの:  someone **who** knows the truth

And so when placed in the larger sentence,

> 真相を知るものは誰もいません: There is no one who knows the truth.

Comment: is it 者 being used in this sentence?

Comment: @FelipeChavesdeOliveira Generally, this もの isn't usually written with kanji.  But I'm not a native speaker and I certainly have read as broadly as a native speaker likely would have.  Nevertheless, 者 seems to me have a rather rigid and formal aspect to it.  Consider reading [「者」と「もの」との違いについて](https://baba.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20140615/p3).

Comment: I think the もの in the original sentence can be safely written as 者. It's not particularly rigid.

Comment: @naruto Thank you for the clarification.  :-)

Comment: Just noticed I said "I certainly have read as broadly" that was supposed to read "I certainly have **not** read as braodly".  Sigh.